# Logging event information for WP7?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

What are some possible methods for logging events and errors in WP7? Are there any third party libraries, resources or maybe even examples of how to do this in WP7? I can imagine there are quite a few ways of doing this, so if you could maybe put an explanation as to why you perfer that method that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used any of these but they may be useful to you:

http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/02/logging-in-silverlight-and-wp7-with-mvvm-light/

http://silverlightlogging.codeplex.com/

http://nlog-project.org/2011/01/09/nlog-for-windows-phone-7.html

http://phoney.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PhoneLogger%20class

http://wp7logging.codeplex.com/